# VB.NET: Add class event at runtime to an interface event

Tags: delegates, event-handling, c#-to-vb.net

I have got a problem with converting an example from C# to VB.NET.

The C# example has the following structure.
First there is a public delegate.

```
public delegate void CustomEventHandler(object sender , EventArgs e);
```

This delegate is connected to an event of an interface.

```
public interface ICustom {
    event CustomEventHandler MyEvent;
}
```

Finally I have got a class with an event related to the delegate. Additionally there is an function with the interface as parameter.

```
public class Test {
    public event CustomEventHandler OnEvent;

    public void MySub(ICustom custom) {
        custom.MyEvent += OnEvent;
    }
}
```

I can convert this code except for adding the class event to the event of the parameter. My VB.NET code looks like the following:

```
Public Delegate Sub CustomEventHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

Public Interface ICustom

    Event MyEvent As CustomEventHandler
End Interface

Public Class Test

    Public Event OnEvent As CustomEventHandler

    Public Sub MySub(ByVal custom As ICustom)
        ... How can I add here the event OnEvent to the event custom.MyEvent? ...
    End Sub
End Class
```

Is it possible to convert this or is there another way necessary.
Thanks for any response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VB.NET version of the Event keyword has much tighter rules, you cannot get to the underlying delegate object.  You'll need to write a custom event so you can:

```
Private BackingField As CustomEventHandler

Public Custom Event OnEvent As CustomEventHandler
    AddHandler(ByVal value As CustomEventHandler)
        BackingField = DirectCast(CustomEventHandler.Combine(BackingField, value), CustomEventHandler)
    End AddHandler

    RemoveHandler(ByVal value As CustomEventHandler)
        BackingField = DirectCast(CustomEventHandler.Remove(BackingField, value), CustomEventHandler)
    End RemoveHandler

    RaiseEvent(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        BackingField.Invoke(sender, e)
    End RaiseEvent
End Event
```

Now you can implement MySub:

```
Public Sub MySub(ByVal custom As ICustom)
    AddHandler custom.MyEvent, BackingField
End Sub
```

Beware that this is the non-threadsafe version of a custom event, you'll need to use SyncLock to make it thread safe if the event can be un/subscribed in another thread.